# CSS grid layout issue - content overlapping template area

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have just started to learn about CSS grid instead of using bootstrap etc,

I have created rows and columns for header, nav, main, aside, footer.

But when I create a `<div>` inside of header it overlaps the boundary and I don't know why. The row height should increase with the content... That is why i used `minmax(150px,auto)`

The html is:

```
<nav>Nav</nav>
<header><div class="header-image"></div></header>
<main>Main</main>
```

The CSS is:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "nav"
  "main"
  "aside"
  "footer";
}
```

```
.header-image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('img/header-img.jpg');
    height: 200px;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is appreciated!

Many thanks!

Edit-

The full WordPress HTML structure is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial theme</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/grid.css'; ?>">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
<header>
        <div class="header-image">
            <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

        <div class="order-div">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
            <button>Order now!</button>
        </div>
    </main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is grid.css

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "nav"
  "main"
  "footer";
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}

nav {
    grid-area: nav;
}


main {
    grid-area: main;
}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(150px, auto) 100px;
        grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "main main main"
        "footer footer footer";
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header header"
            "main main main"
            "footer footer footer";
    }
}
```

This is style.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container > * {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(110,133,156,0.12);
    /*padding: 0.85em;*/
    border: solid 1px rgba(110,133,156,0.15);
}

header {
    background-color: #3f8abf;
}

.header-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('img/header-img.jpg');
    height: 200px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #fbaea8;
}

main {
    background-color: #aad2ed;  
}

aside {
    background-color: #6ad78a; 
}

footer {
    background-color: #6e859c;
}

.order-div {
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.order-div button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

I am hoping it is just a stupid mistake I made but the main problem seems to be the background image in the header - that I set to `background-size:cover` to be responsive!

Many thanks again!

Comment: Can't reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/5qgefu0n/

Comment: please add your full html structure....

Comment: Thank you guys! I have edited my post to include everything! Hoping it is a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting the height for the `grid` yourself. This causes all the rows (grid items) to be the same height (as per `grid` specifications). Then you force one of the rows height to a custom value which is `200px`. This disturbs the layout as these kind of new CSS modules are not so much intelligent to calculate everything. Remove the `100vh` height of the grid and let it adjust itself according to the content.

Comment: No he sets the grid row minmax so minimum is 150 then the maxium is auto so it should adjust per the content inside with the height being at least 150px. He's then got a div in that  which is 200px so the row should adjust accordingly. What is then happening, is below that is a media query so anything 768px and above and in that he's then setting the row height to 100px hence the div inside is then spilling out of the row.

Comment: yeah I actually looked at it for a while. The problem I was telling is that the grid is not supposed to be bigger then 100vh. This actually constraints the minmax. I tried the code without the media query hence the problem is not originating from media query. P.S. he hadn't provided all the code when I started to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue I believe is in your media query as its overriding the css of the one you've set above.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
         grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
         grid-template-rows: 100, minmax(150px, auto) 100;
         grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "main main main"
        "footer footer footer";
    }
}
```

If you edit the "grid-template-rows" section to match your other container minmax(150,auto) like the code below seems to fix the content spilling over.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
         grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
         grid-template-rows:minmax(150px, auto);
         grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "main main main"
        "footer footer footer";
    }
}
```